# EXTJS 6 : Set ComboBox's value when its store is empty

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs6

I'm developing an extjs 6 application and recently figured out that it's not possible to set the value of a ComboBox using the `setValue(value)` method when its store doesn't contain a record with a `valueFiled` equals to `value` as described here
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue.

So my question is is there any other way to change the value of the ComboBox when its store is empty (or doesn't contain a record with `valueFiled` equals to `value`) ?

Comment: Try the [`select()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-select) method.

Comment: I don't understand... according to the doc `select( combo, record, eOpts )`

**Fires when at least one list item is selected**

I don't have any element in my store (its empty) so is the list of items... moreover this method is not used to change value

Comment: I don't think the `select()` method (not event) will work, because in the code that method just calls `setValue()` internally. Why are you trying to set a value when there isn't a list of values to choose from? Maybe you can use the `emptyText` config to display a value when none is set?

Comment: Actually it is an old functional behaviour that was developed with extjs 1 and I'm trying to migrate to version 6. In that version we could set any value to the comboBox regardless the state of the store. For `emptyText ` it's not a solution because the value to set to the comboxBox changes depending on other value selected before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want setRawValue() instead of setValue()

Comment: I ended up using this method, but I had to check if my store is empty or doesn't contain a record with `valueFiled` equals to `value` before using it.
Something like this 
` if (item && item instanceof Ext.form.field.ComboBox && item.getStore().getData().length === 0) {
      item.setRawValue(value);
   } else {
        item.setValue(value);
   }`

Answer (score 1):

You figured it wrong. Please have a look at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12t4, where I got it to work without any problem.

Please check whether it is possible that you have set [`forceSelection: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-forceSelection) on your combo, as this would induce the behaviour you described.

Comment: Actually your example is wrong (compared to my question), just add a `valueField : 'attribute'` to your comboxBox and your example won't work any more... https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/12t4.
Concerning  `forceSelection`, it's kept by default (false)...

Comment: I have added `valueField: 'attribute'` to the example. I don't see any change in behaviour. It is still working.

Comment: Sorry I gave you the wrong link, check this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12to

Comment: I am trying to match your code to your question. Your question is obviously incomplete.